# Angular ui-router not extending parent view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to extend a parent view to a child view.

My route.js

```
let view = {
    '': {
        templateUrl: '/app/content.html'
    },
    'sidebar': {
        templateUrl: '/app/sidebar.html'
    }
};
.state('profile', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/profile',
    views: view,
    templateUrl: '/app/profile/profile.html'
})
.state('profile.about', {
    parent: 'profile',
    url: '/about',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: '/app/profile/about.html'
        }
    }
})
```

My index.html:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

My profile/profile.html:

```
//all other stuff (header, sidebar, etc)
<div>
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```

My profile/about.html:

```
<div>
    <h1>About</h1>
</div>
```

Everything works perfectly including the sidebar.

The problem is that `about.html` is showing the page but it is not extending the `profile/profile.html` page.

Any solutions?

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xPPZdLjArKBH22HHWcyU).

It's a little bit different but it is the same, considering how the `route1` is not shown but the `test.html` is show.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
let view = {
    '': {
        templateUrl: '/app/profile/index.html'
    },
    'content': {
        templateUrl: '/app/content.html'
    },
    'sidebar': {
        templateUrl: '/app/sidebar.html'
    }
};
.state('profile', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/profile',
    views: view
})
.state('profile.about', {
    parent: 'profile',
    url: '/about',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: '/app/profile/about.html'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering. What if I have other page? how can i change dynamically for the let view = {
    '': {
        templateUrl: '/app/profile/index.html'
    }
};